# jQuery Mobile : How to Read Query String Parameters Each Time Page Loads?

Tags: jquery-mobile, query-string, querystringparameter

I am completely new to jQuery and jQuery Mobile and have run into an issue. I have two html pages, one of which is a list of items. Each item links to the main page, and adds ?id=xxx to the url. The main page reads the id and provides content using the following code:

```
       $.urlParam = function(name){
   var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
   return results[1] || 0;
   }
```

I then print the id to the console using

```
   console.log($.urlParam('id'));
```

The first time the page loads the id is correct. When I load the list and select a different item, the id in the URL changes, however the same id as before is printed to the console and the content is not updated. I think that the issue may have to do with the cache. I have tried using a different function (without RegExp) to read the id, but it yields the same issue.

Thanks!

Comment: When are you calling this `urlParam`?

Comment: yes please explain when you are calling for the url.

Comment: urlParam is called when at the beginning of the script which loads the page's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
Why don't you use session storage (if its a mobile website) on the click event of the list item store this selected id into session storage and on the main page live get it back from storage, so you need not pass using query string, generally passing from query string is not safe, and you have limitations on how much data you can pass.
```

Comment: Thanks, good advice but I actually resolved this problem by passing variables between functions in my script so that there was no need for query string params.

Comment: Great!!! Consider the scenario where you have a list page and a details page, when you navigate from list to details page, if we pass parameters from function then when on details page and a refresh or reload is done for the details page, it would loose the param value. This happens specially when there is a mobile website, so hence we proceed with session storage, so that the details page can get the params independently.

Comment: I don't think that refreshes/reloads occur often on mobile pages. The content is updated weekly and the page should only refresh is the user does so intentionally. I understand the use of session storage, however variables are an easier solution.